# how to i get ant-d rowKey?

Tags: next.js, antd

I'm not good at English, so please understand.

My question is like the title.

```
<Table
       columns={[
         {
          key : 1
          title: 'No. ',
          dataIndex: 'id',
          width: 70,
          align: "center"
         },
         {
          key : 2
          title: 'gameState',
          dataIndex: 'gameState',
          width: 70,
          align: "center"
         }]
        dataSource={data}
        pagination={{ pageSizeOptions: ['50', '100'], showSizeChanger: true, position: ['topRight'], pageSize: 20 }}
        scroll={{ y: 550 }}
                        
/>
```

For example, if i want to know the key value of the 2nd row out of several rows, write it this way and i want the result to come out.

```
console.log(2nd rowkey) //2
```